# How do I add the staking part of an address in OffChain code

Tags: plutus, staking, address, offchain

I am currently on tag: v2022-04-06 of plutus-apps and was wondering how to create Lookup and Constraints for a typedValidator that checks whether the input was returned to the script with the correct staking credential. I was hoping to find someone here that could tell me if that is currently possible or not.

In `processConstraint` it also looks like it just uses `Address.scriptHashAddress` to generate the address for this constraint, which does not include any staking credentials. (on tag v2022-04-06)

I have seen a few commit messages in plutus-apps for a new constraint via
`mustPayToOtherScriptAddress` for a later release, but maybe it is already possible and I am just looking in the wrong place.

This is what I currently have written: (it pays to the script but validation fails because it doesn't pay to an address with staking credentials)

```
      l         = Constraints.typedValidatorLookups factoryV <>
                  Constraints.otherScript (Scripts.validatorScript factoryV) <>
                  Constraints.mintingPolicy policy <>
                  Constraints.unspentOutputs utxos

      tx        = Constraints.mustPayToTheScript datum (nftValue) <>
                  -- ?? Constraints.mustPayWithDatumToPubKeyAddress (scriptAddress factoryV) (Nothing) datum (nftValue) <>
                  Constraints.mustMintValue chunkValue <>
                  mconcat [Constraints.mustPayToOtherScript chunkVHash (Datum $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData (ChunkDatum x)) singleCVal | x <- [start..(start+n-1)]] <>
                  Constraints.mustSpendScriptOutput ((Map.keys utxos) !! 0) r
  unbalanced <- adjustUnbalancedTx <$> mkTxConstraints l tx
```

In `factoryV` I just check for the existance

```
    checkStakingCredential :: Bool
    checkStakingCredential = case addressStakingCredential . txOutAddress $ factoryOutput of
      Just _ -> True
      _       -> False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.

After looking at the implementation of `adjustUnbalancedTx` I came up with the following:

```
-- adjust the contracts address to use the given staking credential in the given UnbalancedTx
adjustContractAddress ::
  ValidatorHash ->
  StakingCredential ->
  UnbalancedTx -> UnbalancedTx
adjustContractAddress vH sK =
    over (tx . Tx.outputs . traverse) adjust
  where
    adjust :: TxOut -> TxOut
    adjust txOut = txOut
      { txOutAddress=
        if (addressCredential . txOutAddress) txOut == ScriptCredential vH
        then Address (ScriptCredential vH) (Just sK)
        else txOutAddress txOut
      }
```

using the function above I can now adjust my transaction by changing how I construct it as follows:

```
unbalanced <- adjustContractAddress (Scripts.validatorHash factoryV) (StakingHash $ PubKeyCredential somePubKeyHash) <$> adjustUnbalancedTx <$> mkTxConstraints l tx
```

I hope this will be useful for some of you ;)